# Hurricane: Smoke Simulation too rough and unnatural

Tags: particles, physics, smoke-simulation

I am trying to create a hurricane with a smoke simulation following a particle system. However, the Hurricane looks less detailed, it's blurry and also the particles in the reference image are much crisper. Also the movement is not very smooth. Any advice to tweak it so it matches the reference? Thank you!

[Blender File](https://we.tl/t-dcrFuTqFZu)

[Test Render](https://we.tl/t-vJ467PJX7C)

[image: Reference][image: My Result]

Comment: A smoke simulation with such a low resolution of 60 is not very likely to look crisp. I'm usually only doing explosions, but anyway - a _Resolution Divisions_ setting of 128 is the minimum I use to get some detail...